# Custom user model with Django CMS. Cannot resolve bases for cms.PageUser

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to use custom user model with Django CMS. I created new **users** app with this model:

**users.models:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here project settings:

**settings:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'users',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Why I have this error?

manage.py makemigrations users

```
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'cms.PageUser'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

Comment: Have you done `manage.py makemigrations <app_label>`?

Comment: It might be worth starting again with a fresh blank database and try going a migrate first, then do a makemigration.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into same problem and I followed your instruction but on step 9 I encounter this error:
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.

I got it to work by reordering your step (without commenting out the AUTH_USER_MODEL and without commenting out users from installed apps)

1. Removed migrations folder from users app
2. Started with a blank database
3. Ran manage.py makemigrations users
4. Ran manage.py migrate
5. Ran manage.py makemigrations
6. Ran manage.py migrate

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Based on a reply to https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3436 I did the following which worked for me:

1. Removed migrations folder from users app
2. Commented out users from installed apps
3. Commented out the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` bit
4. Started with a blank database
5. Ran `manage.py makemigrations`
6. Ran `manage.py migrate`
7. Put back the things, I commented out previously.
8. Ran `manage.py makemigrations users`
9. Ran `manage.py migrate`

I know it's an old post but it might help others.